# Store LDAP data in DB?

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, ldap

I have an web application which stores it's data in a PostgreSQL database.
I also have user data like phone numbers, e-mail-addresses... which are needed by the web application stored on a LDAP server.

When a user visits my application, there will be calls to the database and I also need information about the users from the LDAP server.

Is it performant to query the DB and also the LDAP server on every request or should I fetch the user data from the LDAP server and save it into the DB and then update it let's say every 24 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LDAP-queries are really fast and should not really make the application slower. And I would not expect the application to need those informations from the LDAP on every request. So retrieving them when they are needed directly from the LDAP would make more sense for me. Especially as they are always up-to-date then.

When some of those informations belong to the currently logged in user, they might be better of "duplicated" in the database and fetched (and stored) on login of the user.

So all in al, I'd retrieve the informations from DB **and** LDAP depending on where they originate from.